# Android basic programming

Tags: java, android

I want to write an agreement(Long text) of a company and load it while the application starts in a dialog. I have tried loading but the thing is it allows the user to enter the text on that agreement. But what I want is, it should not allow the user to edit the agreement.

Any suggestions for this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText ed;

SharedPreferences sp;
SharedPreferences.Editor sped;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ed=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    sp=getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_APPEND);
    sped=sp.edit();

}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void ShowDialog(View v) {

    showDialog(1);


}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)  {

    switch (id) {
    case 1:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Did you read the policy?");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setMessage("Please wait while we continue");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Accept", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have accepted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Decline", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have declined",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
        default:
            break;

    }

    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use a `TextView` instead of the `EditText`. `TextView`s offer a read-only text display, while `EditText`s are editable.

Comment: Thank you so much.I m gonna try this first. :)